# Displaying the number of correct answers

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a database driven test and need some help with the scoring mechanism.

After selecting their choice of answers and pushing a submit button, users are forwarded to a page that has the following script - an answer key that also counts the questions/answers:

```
$answers = array(1 => array('D'), 
             2 => array('France'), 
             3 => array('B'), 
             4 => array('C', 'D'), 
             5 => array('D'));
$total = count($answers);
```

Most of my tests will have either 10 or 25 questions. In the example above, echoing $total would display 5.

Next is a script that computes the actual score:

```
foreach($answers as $num => $answer){
    $qa = $_POST['q'.$num.''];

if(is_array($answer)){
    if($qa === $answers[$num]){
        $correct++;
    }
} else if($qa === $answers[$num]){
    $correct++;
}

 $grade = ($correct/count($answers))*100;
}
```

...which I display like this:

```
echo '<div style="background: #ff0;">Score: '.$grade.'%</div>';
```

I'd like the final display to look something like this:

**Score:** 90% (9 out of 10 correct)

(using a ten-question quiz as an example)

Displaying "out of 10 correct" is a no-brainer; I simply plug in $total (the number of answers). But **can anyone tell me how to display the number of correct answers (9 in this case)**?

I can make a simple switch that will work for tests that have exactly 10 or 25 answers. But I'd like to have a script that automatically computes the number of correct answers regardless of the total number of answers.

Comment: For # of answers you can most likely get that from the correct database query, and just use PHP to echo it out to the screen.

Comment: Why can't you `'Score: '.$grade.' ('.$correct.' out of '.$answers.')'`?

Comment: Create an array that contains correct answers and check against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do my best to understand what you need, So please try this code:

```
<?php
$answers = array(1 => array('D'), 
             2 => array('France'), 
             3 => array('B'), 
             4 => array('C'), 
             5 => array('D'));
$total = count($answers);

$correct = 0;
foreach($answers as $num => $answer){
    $qa = 'C';  // Change this to your own

if(is_array($answer)){
    if($qa === $answers[$num][0]){ // Added the index 0
        $correct++;
    }
} else if($qa === $answers[$num]){
    $correct++;
}

 $grade = ($correct/count($answers))*100;
}

echo '<div style="background: #ff0;">Score: '.$grade.'%</div>';

?>
```

I've removed 'D' from the index 4, and my changes are in comments.
Tell me if that's work?